# Why does a width of fixed/absolute element fallback to children?

Tags: html, css, react-native

I had to go through a lot of trial and error to restrict the children's widths between the parent's min and max widths. I had to change the position of the parent to either `fixed` or `absolute` to get it to work.

Why does this work?

The question really is on the `header` selector which has `width: 100%`. I had assumed that it will just use up the `max-width` of the parent, but it looks like it calculates its own width after the `content`'s width has been established. This is really confusing, and I was hoping somebody could explain.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  height:  40px;
  background-color: pink;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.header {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.content {
  width: 360px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'></div>
  <div class='content' ></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I added react-native as a tag because this doesn't seem to work on there. But I'd like to fully understand why it does work on the browser, and possibly seek other ways to do it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qz1dos6h/ - "looks fine?" I used width on the parent.

Comment: @user2864740 I modified it to match what I'm confused about https://jsfiddle.net/qz1dos6h/1/

Why does this work is my question.

Comment: @user2864740: Yes, as the question is asking, "Why does this work?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works because the auto width of an absolutely positioned element (which includes fixed positioned elements) is determined using shrink-to-fit. See [section 10.3.7](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) of the CSS2 spec.

The width of `.header`, having been specified as a percentage, cannot be determined until the width of its containing block, that which is established by `.container`, has been determined. (This is true regardless of how the container is displayed or positioned.)

Since the only descendant that provides any sort of width for the absolutely positioned `.container` to determine its width is `.content`, whose width is 360px, the width of `.container` shrinks to fit that 360px, which falls between its `min-width` and `max-width` constraints.

Now that the width of `.container` has been established to be 360px, `.header` can now be sized 100% of that 360px.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I should start a new question, but do you happen to know alternative ways to get this to work? It doesn't seem to be working on react native. Setting the children's width between min and max while being able to use `width: 100%` on one of the children.

Comment: @user1164937: I'm not familiar with React Native so I can't offer much help there. You might look into flexbox... which I'm not well-versed with either.

Comment: I mean, is there a different way to do this on the browser? Crossing my finger at least some of the alternatives on the browser may work

Comment: @user1164937: Yeah, look into flexbox.

Comment: @user1164937 if I understand well, you want the header to push with its width:100% the parent to its max-width? or you want to have the same result as actually with something else?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The latter. I want the header to have the same width as its sibling. So `.content` sets the width, `.container` uses that width as its own, then `.header` looks at the updated `.container`'s width. This is still very weird to me, but it's in the specs

Comment: @user1164937 in this case, simply make the container `display:inline-block` and remove the absolute and also the width:100% from the header .. for the story: inline-block is also shrink-to-fit so it will behave the same as position:absolute.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, I tried it and it worked. But do you know of a way to do it using flexbox? I only have display of flex or none in react native.

Comment: @user1164937 flex won't add a lot here as the key here is  the *shrink-to-fit* so we will also need `inline-flex` and not `flex` : https://jsfiddle.net/2dLy8whx/ ... it's almost the same as inline-block (don't forget to make the direction column)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, that inspired a neat idea to get around react native's support for only display `flex` and display `none`. Just use another root-level container with `flex-direction` of the "shrink to fit" direction (in this case `row`).

Comment: And make sure to use `flex-shrink` and not `flex-grow`. (Note to self)